# A problem about Partial Differential Equations with IVP.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can I solve this problem ?:

\begin{align}
\mbox{Find}\ \mathrm{u}\left(x,t\right)\ \mbox{such that}\ &
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathrm{u}_{\, t} & = & \mathrm{u}_{\,xx} + 3
\\[1mm]
\mathrm{u}\left(0, t\right)& = & 2 - t, &
\\[1mm]
\mathrm{u}_{x}\left(\pi, t\right) & = & \mathrm{e}^{2t} - 4
\\[1mm]
\mathrm{u}(x, 0)& = & 1 + \mathrm{e}^{x}
\end{array}\right.
\\[3mm] &\
\mbox{where}\ 0 \leq x \leq \pi\ \mbox{and}\ t > 0.
\end{align}

---

**My attempt:** Suppose that
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_{n}(t)\sin(n \pi x)
$$
so, we have that
$$
\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_{n}(t)(-n^{2}\pi^{2})\sin(n \pi x) \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_{n}'(t)\sin(n \pi x)
$$
Also, suppose that $F(x,t)=3$ we can write as $$
3=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}F_{n}(t)\sin( n \pi x)\implies F_{n}(t)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}3 \sin( n \pi x)dx$$.
Then
$$
3=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi}3 \sin( n \pi x)dx \right) \sin(n \pi x)
$$
Now, we have
\begin{align}
&\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_{n}(t)(-n^{2}\pi^{2})\sin(n \pi x)  \right]+\left[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{\pi}3 \sin( n \pi x)dx \right) \sin(n \pi x)\right]
\\[2mm] = &
\left[\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_{n}'(t)\sin(n \pi x)\right]
\end{align}
It's ODE of first order.

But I don't know how to continue.

I think that if a used Fourier transform or Laplace transformation it should be easy.

Comment: Your equation is of $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tt first\ order}$ on $\displaystyle\color{red}{t}$. You must have $\displaystyle\color{red}{\tt just\ one}$ initial condition: For example, $\displaystyle\mathrm{u}\left(x,\color{red}{0}\right)$.

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry. Can you explain me more details?

Comment: I know my equation is of first order on t.